# iOS5 - custom form API's

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, forms, ios5, customization

I'm creating an iPhone application that requires a user entering information into a form, and then sending that data to a cloud server. Are there any good customizable-form API's that can be easily deployed on a storyboard in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, [QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/quickdialog) could be suitable for you.

Comment: do you know for fact if this works with XCode 4? basically will this function with story boards and such? since I'm new to this, I've decided to learn only iOS5 for the time being

Comment: Since I have never used it (but I intend to do so), I can not say for sure. However, it is an active project with last changes a couple of hours ago, thus I am strongly believe that it will run with XCode 4.

Comment: I'm the maintainer: It requires XCode 4.3, although the community is helping maintain compatibility with 4.2. It doesn't directly support anything else.